# how to build android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

It is a absolutely nightmare. How the hell I get a (older?) android app project from github up and running. I want to add some features to the app, so I need a working local build environment. The following Project I try to get up and running locally in Android Studio:

https://github.com/abarisain/dmix

But all I get are errors.

So far I've spent almost a whole day on it.
Can someone please describe  the process how to do this right?

My aim are: Get the app mpdroid + the dev environment up and running in the Android Studio so I can add some features.

Thank you

Comment: That project has not been maintained in several years and its origins are ancient. It is unclear how well it was built with Android Studio 1.0, let alone with modern versions of that IDE. If you have extensive Android app development experience, "the process how to do this right" is probably what you are doing: try opening the project, then fix the errors one by one. If you do not have extensive Android app development experience, you may be better served starting over and leveraging bits of code from that project as appropriate.

Comment: Make sure to set JDK 8 as JAVA_HOME before starting gradle on command-line. With newer JDK Gradle nor Android Gradle plugin will most likely not work. Not sure if Android SDK still support such old projects. Older Android Studio projects are AFAIR available for download but not Android SDK.